# .NET/C# DB2 for iSeries 'FatalExecutionEngineError' from IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries

Tags: c#, .net, db2, ibm-midrange

Having trouble connecting from a C#/.NET program to a Development (non-live) iSeries

Getting the following failure when trying to open a new connection:-

"Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown."

HResult -2146233082

Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem in 'C:\Users\sclose\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\iSeries1\iSeries1\bin\Debug\iSeries1.vshost.exe'.

Additional information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x71ccec3c, on thread 0x28bc. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

Just a very simple noddy program which sets a connection string and opens a new connection:-

```
        string ConnectionString = "DataSource=MACH03Y;UserID=sysmon;Password=xxxxxxxxx;LibraryList=U1SCLOSE;Naming=System";

        _connection = new iDB2Connection(ConnectionString);
```

Have iAccess for Windows 7.1 installed and am able to connect and sign on to the iSeries through System i Navigator

Tried:-

1) Various combinations of UserId's and Library lists (valid and invalid)

2) Valid and Invalid DataSource values

3) Different IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.dll versions including the latest

Always the same failure

We know the same code works successfully in a live environment but this is maybe first time it's been tried in a dev environment!

Normally in dev it uses a mock service and goes nowhere near a real iSeries

I have more experience on the iSeries side than the .NET side

Thinking it's maybe a Network/Firewall issue?

Any help gratefully received

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have seen this error, it has been a problem with the Visual Studio Debugger. I do not think it is a problem with your code or the IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.dll.

Error code 5 is an access violation in Windows. These debugger crashes are usually fixed by upgrading Visual Studio or applying the latest service pack.  VS2015 is screwy in lots of ways, since it was a ground up rewrite, and I had these errors a few years ago until they fixed them.  Try a service pack first.  If that doesn't help, try either version 2012 or 2017.  There also conceivably could be a Windows update that broke this.  It has happened before.

See also:  ["vshost32.exe has stopped working" OR "fatal execution engine error" in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29533969/vshost32-exe-has-stopped-working-or-fatal-execution-engine-error-in-visual-s)

Comment: Thanks, that's useful to know, I'll try a different version of VS

Comment: Sadly, exactly the same failure when using VS2012