# Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' with DB2.Iseries connection

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, fatal-error, iseries-navigator

I am getting below exception when trying to establish a connection with IBM DB2 iseries database in visual studio 2019. I have tried with .NET framework project and .NET Core projects separately but no luck. Debug option I kept as "Any CPU", not sure what's causing this exception. I am using IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries NuGet package. Please suggest if you are already aware of this issue.

Exception Details:

Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' : 'The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0xd379fa25, on thread 0x4a24. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.'

Comment: Did you take a look at this issue? They mention that it may be a debugger issue and you should check your VS and OS versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262118/net-c-db2-for-iseries-fatalexecutionengineerror-from-ibm-data-db2-iseries